# Structure project using Vue Storefront and Magento 2

Tags: magento2, git, deployment, pwa, headless

Right now I have a Magento 2 installation which is run through a customized vagrant box, and I would like to use VS for the frontend, but I’m a little confused on how to best handle deployment to different environments and
how to structure the git repository in this case?
I’m thinking about creating two separate repositories one for Vue Storefront and one for Magento and then run the VS part directly from my local computer, while the Magento 2 application will be run from the vagrant box.
I am using the composer to install the Magento 2 part. Does this seem to be a valid setup or is there a better and more standard approach?
One other thing that is confusing is the fact that the recommendation for VS is not to run Elastic search and Redis through docker containers in a production environment but instead install everything locally on the server. It seems like it could be hard to create a valid deployment for local/stage and production machines.

I would be glad for any help/tips on how to best handle this kind of setup.

Comment: How you deployed/managed both Magento and VS source

Comment: @TamilvananN - Currently I have one repository for everything. I'm using ansible to clone the needed vue-storefront repositories e.g `vue-storefront`, `vue-storefront-api` and `mage2vuestorefront`. The ansible playbook of course also installs anything needed to run vs and magento. In staging environment I'm using `systemd` to restart the different vs parts using something like this `sudo service vue-storefront restart`. This is a pretty wide area to discuss like this =) I'm using nginx to route different requests to magento and vue-storefront.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently building a vagrant environment that allows quick and easy setup of local Dev environment with magento2 and vue storefront.

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/vagrant_m2_vuestorefront

Still WIP, but already functional.

I don't like running things on my host, especially with multiple development in a team. It brings in inconsistencies in environment, with non repeatable issues.

Once done, I will be looking at version control structures (once actually working on theme etc) and then how to do a easy to live deployment using containers in the same way.
(Most likely using docker compose, or kubernetes)